# How can I limit the log to commits that affected a given path, but see *all* the changes made in those commits?

Tags: git, git-log

I am using `git log` to look at changes that affected a particular subdirectory:

```
git log -p <dirname>
```

This shows me commits that affect this directory, but any other changes in the same commit are not shown. I want to see them: They are things like related top-level Makefile fixes.

At the moment I am copying the commit hash for interesting commits by hand, and looking at that commit separately to see all the changes. How can I get git log to show **all** the changes in the limited set of commits I'm interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
git log -p `git rev-list HEAD -- <path>`
```

where `<path>` corresponds to the file/directory of interest (thanks to torek).

Basically,

```
git rev-list HEAD -- <path>
```

produces a list of revisions that affected `<path>`, which you then pass this list to `git log -p` via command substitution.

Comment: I don't think that's quite what he wants - he wants to pick commit IDs in terms of "all commits that touch a file within the given sub-path" but then look at the commit log and diff for those commits, without the restriction of "given sub-path". The inner `git log -n 1` will find only the first such commit. So I think he wants `git log -p --no-walk $(git rev-list -- dirname)`.